# Share only Image and url on linkedIn

Tags: c#, asp.net, linkedin-api

[image]

So this is normal linkedIn post.

I want to only share image and url without the title and description. So that the whole post will basically be an image.

Something like below:

[image]

I have tried keeping the title and description empty but it doesn't work.

```
var shareMessage=
    new
    {
        content =
            new
            {
                title ="",
                submitted_url = "http://www.example.com",
                submitted_image_url = "http://www.example.com/images/someimage.jpg",
                description = ""
            },
            //comment = "Comment:" + LINKEDIN.POST_CONTENT,
            visibility = new { code = LINKEDIN.VISIBILITY }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if you want to know why LinkedIn interprets your site as it does within the share preview, check out the LinkedIn Inspector, for your site: [**LinkedIn Inspector: LiveMint.com**](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/https:%2F%2Fwww.livemint.com%2FSearch%2FLink%2FKeyword%2FReliance%2520Jio).

If I want to know, for instance, why the Title is showing (which you want to hide), click the Title at the Inspector page.  For your page, with regards to Title, I see...

> Title
> Note: We used the value from the provided Open Graph tag on the page.
>
> How to change the title
>
> Provide a metadata tag for the og:title in the page's head section. For example:
>
> `<meta name="title" property="og:title" content="[Content title here]">`

Of course, it is right, I do see this in your page...

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Reliance Jio: Top and Latest News, Videos and Photos about Reliance Jio"/>
```

Unfortunately, I think you have only the option of altering your `og:title` tag, which is bad advice, because other services will depend on this.  Otherwise, unfortunately, you have no real alternatives.